# localytics did not give report?

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, analytics

I have registered as free user and integrated localytics in iphone4 app.i have used API Key they have given.but i could not see reports after logging in.i have checked the app through tagging some events.How much time will be taken to give? any help? I did not upgrade..is it need?

Comment: for me it took only 5 min to update.

Answer (score 1):

Community customers should expect to see their data in at most a few hours after logging their sessions. If you check the console log while you run the app in the simulator you should see traces from Localytics confirming that data collection is working and being uploaded. Are you using Phonegap or another tool? If so, there are some additional debugging steps required to make sure everything is working.

Feel free to contact me directly: henry@localytics.com and I will be glad to make sure everything is working correctly for you.

-- Henry